# How to fix 'ValueError("input must have more than one sentence")' Error

Tags: python-3.x, beautifulsoup, gensim

Im writing a script that takes a website url and downloads it using beautiful soup. It then uses gensim.summarization to summarize the text but I keep getting ValueError("input must have more than one sentence") even thought the text has more than one sentence. The first section of the script works that downloads the text but I cant get the second part to summarize the text.

```
import bs4 as bs
import urllib.request
from gensim.summarization import summarize
from gensim.summarization.textcleaner import split_sentences

#===========================================

print("(Insert URL)")
url = input()
sauce = urllib.request.urlopen(url).read()
soup = bs.BeautifulSoup(sauce,'lxml')

#===========================================

print(soup.title.string)
with open (soup.title.string + '.txt', 'wb') as file:
    for paragraph in soup.find_all('p'):
        text = paragraph.text.replace('.', '.\n')
        text = split_sentences(text)
        text = summarize(str(text))
        text = text.encode('utf-8', 'ignore')

#===========================================

        file.write(text+'\n\n'.encode('utf-8'))
```

It should create a .txt file with the summarized text in it after the script is run in whatever folder the .py file is located

Comment: I can only assume 1 (or possibly more) elements from your 'soup.find_all(‘p’)' is at some point in the iteration identifying 'text' as a single sentence. Either have your loop skip when 'text' is 1 sentence, or identify at what point the script breaks by printing off the sentences to identify the specific point that it throws the error to see how to fix it.

Comment: Have you also considered abbreviations and other considerations with “.”, with your replace? A period could come after Mr., Mrs., Jr., $5.00, etc. and you’ll be adding a new line at those points as well. Then there’s also other punctuation that denotes an end of sentence “?”, “!”

Answer (score 1):

You should not use `split_sentences()` before passing the text to `summarize()` since `summarize()` takes a string (with multiple sentences) as input.

In your code you are first turning your text into a list of sentences (using `split_sentences()`) and then converting that back to a string (with `str()`). The result of this is a string like `"['First sentence', 'Second sentence']"`. It doesn't make sense to pass this on to `summarize()`.

Instead you should simply pass your raw text as input:

```
text = summarize(text)
```

Comment: I tried removing the text = split_sentences(text) line and let the raw input be summarized however I still get the same error without this line in the script ValueError("input must have more than one sentence")

Comment: Okay, strange. Maybe you can try to print `split_sentences(text)` to see how gensim splits your text into sentences? Or maybe you have one paragraph with only one sentence?

Comment: It seems to only give me one sentence no matter the website I use which makes me think that it is a problem with gensim itself and not my code

Comment: @TheBluesBand isn't it a problem that you replace dots '.' with the new line char '\n' ?